# How to do a "Pointer to Pointer" in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I have a data structure similar to a List, but I could not use any built-in containers (List<> etc.). I'd like to keep a "pointer to pointer" aka "tail", which point to the tail of this list. It should like this in C++:

```
class MyList {
  Node* head;
  Node** tail;  // tail is just a pointer to the "next" pointer of the end of the list.
  MyList() {
    head = null;
    tail = &head;
  }
  bool isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
  }
  void add(int val) {
    *tail = new Node();
    (*tail)->val = val;
    tail = &((*tail)->next);
  }
}
```

How to implement this in C#? Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to do this using pointers, references are quite enough. However, why are you even doing this? You should explain the problem you're trying to solve instead, because you're most likely thinking about this wrong. Transliterating C++ to C# is usually a bad idea. What's wrong with `List[List.Count - 1]`? Also, if you want a linked list, why not use the builtin `LinkedList`? :)

Comment: Don't try to mix apples with oranges

Comment: Ah.. there we go. thanks. mucho clearer.

Comment: @Luaan How to do this with references?

Comment: Generally I think the easiest way would be for the nodes themselves to contain the reference to the next node

Comment: Well, you'd just keep a reference to the tail node and use that reference to get to the `next` value. I think you're misunderstanding some fundamental difference between C++ and C#. Why would you want to use a pointer to a pointer to do this? I think you're overcomplicating this a lot. Why can't you use List/LinkedList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, C# cannot (safely) implement a pointer-to-pointer. As a result cute code like yours is not possible. This is the best I can do.

```
public class Node {
  public Node next;
  public int val;
}
class MyList {
  Node head = null;
  Node tail = null;
  public MyList() { }
  bool isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
  }
  void add(int val) {
    if (isEmpty())
      head = tail = new Node();
    else {
      tail.next = new Node();
      tail = tail.next;
    }
    tail.val = val;
  }
}
```

It's not bad, is it? Almost exactly the same length and (I would argue) slightly easier to understand.

There are powerful features in C++ that are not available in C#, but in my experience C# is a significantly more productive language, even for low level code like this.

If you have some other code that you think will not yield to this kind of simple translation please post and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 4):

How about using a [LinkedList](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linkedlist) instead of the List<>...?

Comment: Thanks. But my example is just an abstraction of my problem, it's similar, but not the same. In real case, I cannot use any of those built-in containers.

Comment: @JASON - Would you mind going a bit deeper into detail as to what you want to do that you (think you) cannot do with built-in containers?