# How do I make List<T> include item as variables references (ref item)?

Tags: c#

Assume we have some codes

```
public class A { }

public class B : A { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a1 = new A();
    A a2 = new A();
    A a3 = new A();
    Process(ref a1);
    Console.WriteLine(a1.GetType().Name == "B"); // show True : that i want
    List<A> list = new List<A>();
    list.Add(a2);
    list.Add(a3);
    ProcessList(ref list);
    Console.WriteLine(a2.GetType().Name == "B"); // False : I want True
    Console.WriteLine(a3.GetType().Name == "B"); // False : I want True
    Console.Read();
}

static void ProcessList(ref List<A> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = new B();
    }
}

static void Process(ref A item)
{
    item = new B();
}
```

As marked **ref** in ProcessA method I can change `A` type variable object of caller (Main) to `B` type. But like that, when I want to process list of `A` in **ProcessList** I can't make `A` type variable object of caller (Main) to `B` type.

It seems `List<T>` does pass its item by reference; or how can I make this happen?

Comment: Why you make ProcessA a generic method and named `A` generic type? that would override access to type `A`.

Comment: also you are just passing list by ref. the elements of list are not passed by ref. When you call `list.Add(a)` as you see its not `list.Add(ref a)`. you have to create your own custom class that takes items by ref.

Comment: What you are asking is effectively to do is to have in your list pointers to pointers (or in the C# vernacular, "references to references"). C# doesn't have that feature. See the marked duplicate for more details.

Comment: @LeQuangHoa You can do it like this:  `public class Box<TItem>
    {
        private Action<TItem> _onReplace;
        public Box(TItem item, Action<TItem> onReplace)
        {
            this.Item = item;
            this._onReplace = onReplace;
        }
        public void Replace(TItem item)
        {
            this.Item = item;
            this._onReplace(item);
        }
        public TItem Item { get; private set; }
    }`

Comment: Then change these lines in `Main`:  `List<Box<A>> list = new List<Box<A>>(); list.Add(new Box<A>(a2, r => a2 = r)); list.Add(new Box<A>(a3, r => a3 = r));`

Comment: Then change `ProcessList` to look like `static void ProcessList(List<Box<A>> list)`  And then inside change the assignment `=` to `list[i].Replace(new B());`

Comment: Looks like question is very close to be re-opened - would be interesting to see if someone comes up with anything better than "no" as covered in current duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054186/how-to-do-a-pointer-to-pointer-in-c (which I think relatively good one for this post).